If the SDK isn't collecting user data, do we still need to include a privacy manifest into the iOS SDK project?
Presently, we are implementing a Bluetooth iOS SDK, which does not gather user data or tracking user data. Therefore, my inquiry is whether it's necessary to include a privacy manifest in the iOS SDK project.
we already added privacy manifest into iOS SDK.

What exactly do you mean? Are you asking if your framework should include a privacy manifest or applications that include your framework? You mentioned you already added a privacy manifest to your framework.

From me experience, if the privacy manifest is empty (doesn't include any APIs, tracking, etc.,) it's not necessary to add it. When you submit the final app to App Store Connect, it only shows you warnings, if the app contains not declared APIs. This also is indirectly confirmed by Apple open-source libraries (like swift-collections,) which don't include declarable APIs and don't have privacy manifests.

@tomerpacific Do we need to add  privacy manifest or not in SDK, as we are not tracking user data?

If it would be empty, you should not add it. Unless you repackage another SDK that does require one.
From the forums:

If your framework doesn't require a privacy manifest, do nothing. Avoid adding an empty privacy manifest to your framework.


{...} Confirm that your framework doesn't repackage an SDK on the list of third-party SDKs requiring a privacy manifest and signature. If your framework does, then you need to add a privacy manifest to it.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/746481?answerId=782256022#782256022
